# ReadTimeoutError: Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, sockets, twitter, streaming, twython

I want to get some tweets regarding aggressive dogs. My keywords are specified in the code. All of them refer to German shepherd (In Spanish "pastor alemán").
For instance, among other tweets I expect to get [this one](https://twitter.com/EducaRacional/status/569847674305953793) that perfectly fits the keywords and was posted on 23 Feb 2015.
I executed the below-given code and after around 1 hour of waiting the following error appeared:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

It seems that there is some problem with the port 443. How to solve this problem?

P.S. The code works fine with keywords like "python, javascript".

**UPDATE:**
I noticed that the code retrieves some tweets if I write keywords in English, like "German shepherd aggressive". But then I receive another error message:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

My code:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = "..."
CONSUMER_SECRET = "..."
ACCESS_TOKEN = "..."
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "..."

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print data
            saveFile = open('raw_tweets.json', 'a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True

        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
            time.sleep(10)
            pass

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
        if status == 420:
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    stream = Stream(auth, listener())

    keywords = ['pastor aleman agresivo','pastor aleman muerde',
                'pastor aleman mata','pastor aleman muerte',
                'pastor aleman peligroso','pastor aleman peligro',
                'pastor aleman adiestramiento']
    stream.filter(track=keywords)
```

Comment: I've answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47865652/3478114).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch these errors and restart the stream. The errors are normal. Connections may break for a number of reasons you have no control over. Also, Twitter will close the connection if there is no activity after 90 seconds.

EDIT:
Someone posted an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601634/how-to-restart-tweepy-script-in-case-of-error) using tweepy that does something similar to what you need.

Comment: Can you put some example how to restart the stream?

Comment: I don't use tweepy. I use [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). [Example](http://geduldig.github.io/TwitterAPI/faulttolerance.html).