# How to run two function in the same time with using try exception block

Tags: python, python-multithreading, try-except

from [Make 2 functions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time) by using thread. It can make two function with the same time. Is it possible to call function with thread in try except block?

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time

def queryRepeatedly():
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                Thread(target = foo).start()
                Thread(target = bar).start()
                print ''
            except:
                continue
            else:
                break

def foo():
      print 'foo'
      time.sleep(1)
def bar():
      print 'bar'
      time.sleep(3)

queryRepeatedly()
```

This my code not work,i need to run two function separately with try except block. what should i do?

Comment: could you explain why do you have two while True ? 
Also, what errors are you trying to catch ? 
Do you have a traceback ?

Comment: am following [Restarting a program after exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533104/restarting-a-program-after-exception) it can merge two loop into one. I have two function, first is write data to Database(Influxdb) and second is query data from  database. I need to catch error time out of first function.

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Comment: Sorry for late, i just tried it this moning. and it's work for me, Thank you very much.@Mium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time

def queryRepeatedly():
   Thread(target = foo).start()
   Thread(target = bar).start()

def foo():
    while True:
        try:
            print 'foo'
        except : #catch your error here
           pass # handle your error here
        finally:
           time.sleep(1)
def bar():
    While True:
        try:
           print 'bar'
        except : #catch your error here
           pass # handle your error here
        finally:
           time.sleep(3)

queryRepeatedly()
```